# IP Address while using a VPN

Tags: vpn, ip-address

In my website, i am using IP2Location service for finding visitor's country. But in some cases, even if the user visiting from India, the country returned is USA. I guess these users are using VPN connection. If so, how can i access visitor's actual location if they are using VPN connections ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant. That is why a VPN is used. So people can keep Anonymous online. Virtual Private Network. Privacy is key. If the User did not care they wouldn't be using a VPN. or It may be how the corporate network is being used. So the user has no choice but to use the ip the company has assigned them.

Their is an issue with WEBRTC located in Web Browsers that could possibly leak the real IP if the user is not careful. You can read about that [Here](http://whatismyipaddress.com/vpn-leaking)

The IP of the User if they are on a VPN is going to be wherever the VPN is located. Not where the User may be located.

Comment: The "P" in "VPN" doesn't really refer to privacy though – it means private in the sense of "privately managed" (i.e. a LAN). It just happens that VPNs ended up being commonly used for Internet access.

Comment: @grawity I understand that. I was just Explaining how others view a VPN. I've hosted a Few for access purposes for different applications. I do thank you for adding insight.